# Processing excel file attached in a custom entity record in Dynamic CRM Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using Dynamic CRM Online

I have a plugin that is attached to a custom entity that is triggered on update.
The particular custom entity have an excel file attached to it in it's annotation.

I need to process that excel file (reading the content) in the plugin.

My Logical steps goes as follows:

- Read the annotation document body
- Convert the base64 string inside to byte[]
- Open the excel file from the byte array

In my current understanding, using Microsoft.Office.Interop I'm not able to open an excel file from the byte[]. I also tried using 3rd party library (SpreadsheetGear) but a trust issue comes up (since dynamic CRM online only enabled sandbox plugin).

Any advise how to do it? Or is it actually not recommended to process excel file in Dynamic CRM Plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office automation is not supported or even recommended in server side by Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Newest Excel version are just a zip file witha bunch of xml inside, so it's no so hard to process. And you could integrate code from some projects like these:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/
http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/
http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/